# How does $Z(G/Z_i(G)) = Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)$ imply $HZ_i(G) \lhd HZ_{i+1}(G)$ for any $H \le G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of why every subgroup of a nilpotent group is subnormal, and the author makes the above claim without any explanation.

I've alternatively shown that every subgroup is subnormal, but the claim above bothers me still as to where it's coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $HZ_i\triangleleft HZ_{i+1}$ as $HZ_{i+1}$ normalizes $HZ_i$, which is equivalent to say that $H$ and $Z_{i+1}$ normalize $HZ_i$; proving this last is then easy:

(1) $H$ normalizes $HZ_i$: this is true because $H$ normalizes $H$ itself and $Z_i$ are normal in $G$ means they are normalized by everything, so by $H$.

(2) $Z_{i+1}$ is *by definition* subgroup of $G$ such that modulo $Z_i$ it becomes central, i.e. $Z_{i+1}/Z_i$ commutes with everything in $G/Z_i$,

i.e. $Z_{i+1}/Z_i$ *centralizes* $g/Z_i$, and so it centralizes subgroup $HZ_i/Z_i$;

in particalar $Z_{i+1}/Z_i$ *normalizes* $HZ_i/Z_i$;

Hence $Z_{i+1}$ normalizes $HZ_i$ (because, if we have normal subgroup $N$, and a subgroup $M$ with

$$N\subseteq M\subseteq G$$

then $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$ if and only if $M$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: mod out by $Z_{i}(G)$ and use the correspondence theorem. Use that any subgroup is normalized by the center of the full group.